# Duplicate a sheet everday

Tags: google-sheets

I need to do a script that duplicates a sheet (only with values and format, I don't want to copy the formulas) on a daily basis and gives to the new sheet (copy values) a name that is in the source sheet (today date). Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible. This is too broad to be answered, since there are many ways to create a copy of a Google Sheet. For example, you could use third party programs, native Google Apps Script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you will first need to create a program which will only copy the values and format and make sure that the program has assess to the sheet. Then add a function that will do this everyday.
[click here to look at a example of a program to copy and paste](https://github.com/roshancode/fluffy-system/tree/master)
By the way I created this program for Excel since I don't really use Google Sheets but it's basically the same thing.

Comment: I know but the program I created can used for both.